# PHP, cURL, SendinblueAPI : how to code the filebody in order to import CSV file?

Tags: php, curl, sendinblue

Im writing a script in PHP and cURL using sendinBlue API.
This script have to send contact from a CSV file to my datebase in the website sendinBlue.

This API got a documentation : https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#importcontacts-1

I would like for exemple import theses 2 contacts :

```
dupont.jean@aol.com;Dupont;Jean;0645342891;2;2019-12-01 19:00:21;false;true;false
dupont2.jean@aol.com;Dupontt;maurice;0645342892;3;2019-12-01 19:00:21;false;true;false
```

So i have this code :

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/import",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"fileBody\":\"dupont.jean@aol.com;Dupont;Jean;0645342891;2;2019-12-01 19:00:21;false;true;false; 
                                dupont2.jean@aol.com;Dupontt;maurice;0645342892;3;2019-12-01 19:00:21;false;true;false\",
                                \"listIds\":[2],\"emailBlacklist\":false,\"smsBlacklist\":false,
                                \"updateExistingContacts\":true,\"emptyContactsAttributes\":true}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "api-key: ****",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```

But this is not working, i have this error : `{"error":{"status":400,"message":"Input must be a valid JSON object","code":"bad_request"}}`

Ive tried to import only one contact, with only the email with this code :

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/import",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"fileBody\":\"dupont.jean@aol.com",
                                \"listIds\":[2],\"emailBlacklist\":false,\"smsBlacklist\":false,
                                \"updateExistingContacts\":true,\"emptyContactsAttributes\":true}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "api-key: ****",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```

And this one is working, the contact is in my data base : 
[image]

But that not enougth because all is empty and i would like to send multiple contact at the same time ! (almost 10 000 contacts!).

Would you please help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The param `fileBody` should be similar to .csv or .txt, see the Example [here](https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/208729849-What-are-the-rules-for-importing-a-contact-file-).

And my codes with Guzzle look like this:

```
$fileBody = "EMAIL;FIRSTNAME;LASTNAME" . " \n" .
            "junie3@example.com;Junie;JL" . " \n" .
            "john@example.com;John;JohnL";

$client = new Client([
    'headers' => [
        'api-key' => $apiKey
    ]
]);
$client->post($apiUrl . '/contacts/import', [
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
        'fileBody' => $fileBody,
        'listIds' => [$listId],
        'updateExistingContacts' => true,
    ]
]);
```

- I wrote "rowtext" . " \n" because you'll need to enter row text dynamically.
- I wrote " \n" instead of "\n" because it doesn't store last column data (LASTNAME in my example) just with "\n".
- It won't work if you change double quotes to single ones.